# Plot 3D points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I want to plot 3D points in `Matlab` in different colors depending on a value. I've got following code, but this does not work because `plot3d` needs a vector.

```
x = vdhf_data.data(:,1);
y = vdhf_data.data(:,2);
z = vdhf_data.data(:,3);
data = vdhf_data.data(:,4);

grid on
hold all

for k=1:length(x)
    if data(k) < 6  
        plot3d(x(k), y(k), z(k), 'ws--', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'r', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r')
    else
        plot3d(x(k), y(k), z(k), 'ws--', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'g', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'g')
    end
end
```

How to do that in Matlab?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use

```
scatter3(x,y,z,ones(size(x)),data,'filled')
```

This will plot all the points at the same size and color them according to the value of data, using the current colormap. You can also use data to scale the size of each point.

```
scatter3(x,y,z,data.^-2,data,'filled')
```

Comment: I believe instead of `ones(size(x))` the size vector in scatter3 can be scalar value for the same size or an empty (`[]`) for default size.

Comment: Yes there can be a scalar. I only want to have two markercolors. Is there a possibility to add this in one line instead of a loop?

Comment: You will just need to adjust your colormap. So for two colors (red & blue)you will do something like this `colormap([ones(50,1)*[1 0 0]; ones(50,1)*[0 0 1]])` This will make the color division in the middle of the data range. If you want it to be at a specific number you have to scale the ones(n-a,1) ones(n+a,1) accordingly